# How to understand this React code that conditionally displays markup?

Tags: reactjs

Trying to find a React-equivalent to this Vue.js statement:

```
<div v-show="showSiteMenuArea">the menu</div>
```

in React, I came upon this syntax which works nicely:

```
{this.state.showSiteMenuArea && (
    <div>the menu</div>
)}
```

and while I now use this pattern often to conditionally display blocks of markup, I can't say I logically understand it. It seems to mean,

`if <expression1> and <expression2> then display <expression2>`

which seems absurd. Or how does one understand this?

Comment: What does a JS logical expression return? (And why does it "seem absurd"?)

Comment: it is nothing, but js-expression `this.state.showSiteMenuArea && <div>the menu</div>`, first part is boolean and second part is jsx-object

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#Description could explain `&&` behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Such expression:

```
return this.state.showSiteMenuArea && <div>the menu</div>
```

Exploits [short circuit](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Short-circuit_evaluation) evaluation of the [`&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) (just Javascript).

Since in React, boolean values such as `true` and `false` [are **valid** React elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored), if the expression is falsy it just won't render a thing:

```
return false;
```

> `false`, `null`, `undefined`, and `true` are **valid** children. They simply don’t render.

And of course if its truthy, you render the element.

- See [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) for more info

---

Notice the gotchas when you overuse such pattern, for example:

```
// render `0` when falsy
array.length && <div>Oh No</div>

// instead
array.length > 0 && <div>Oh Yes</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's what I meant by this seeming absurd, since as you say, if the expression is falsy, it will return `false`. It would seem logical then that if the expression is truthy, it would return `true`. But instead of returning true if truthy, it returns the last item in the expression, which in this case happens to be a React element.

Answer (score 0):

It actually means "run the expression `<div>the menu</div>` if `this.state.showSiteMenuArea` is truthy"

The whole expression will return the value of `this.state.showSiteMenuArea` if it is falsy, and `<div>the menu</div>` if truthy.

This is a shorthand for rendering something based on a boolean condition.